# Swift - Weird 'Metal' Crashes

Tags: swift, camera, buffer, metal

I have a random weird crash when I am launching this code for the camera.
The error message is pointed on the line below : *videoPreviewView.bindDrawable()*

```
func setupVideoPreviewView() {
        glContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        if let eaglContext = glContext {
            videoPreviewView = GLKView(frame: self.view.bounds, context: eaglContext)
            ciContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext)
        }
        if let videoPreviewView = videoPreviewView {
            videoPreviewView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = false
            videoPreviewView.frame = self.view.bounds
            videoPreviewView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            self.view.addSubview(videoPreviewView)
            self.view.sendSubview(toBack: videoPreviewView)
        }

        resizePreviewView()
    }

    // MARK: Update
    func resizePreviewView() {
        guard let videoPreviewView =  videoPreviewView else {
            print("can't resize preview vide")
            return
        }

        videoPreviewView.frame = self.view.bounds
        videoPreviewView.bindDrawable()
        videoPreviewViewBounds = CGRect.zero
        videoPreviewViewBounds?.size.width = self.view.bounds.width * videoPreviewView.contentScaleFactor
        videoPreviewViewBounds?.size.height = self.view.bounds.height * videoPreviewView.contentScaleFactor
    }
```

The debug shows :

**018-12-21 -[MTLIOAccelCommandBuffer validate]: error 'commit command buffer with uncommitted encoder'**

Anyone has a clue to fix this problem ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Are you using bgfx by any chance? Because I'm getting the same error.